# Why do FFT result show 2 non-zero amplitudes for a samples of single frequency?

Tags: python, numpy, fft

Doing a simple FFT run to learn the operation, I create an NumPy array with 100 elements having a sine wave with only a single period in the array.  This code is used:

```
...
n = 100
x = np.fromfunction(lambda a: np.sin(2 * np.pi * a / n), (n,), dtype=float)
res = np.fft.fft(x)
...
```

The result in `res` shows an non-zero amplitude at 2 different index value:

```
idx           real         imag          abs
---     ----------   ----------   ----------
...
  1:             0      -50.000       50.000
...
 99:             0       50.000       50.000
```

I had only expected to see a single non-zero amplitude at index 1.

Why is amplitude non-zero for both index 1 and 99, and how can I understand this mathematically?

ADDITION: Maybe the high frequency actually represent an [aliased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing#Sampling_sinusoidal_functions) frequency, where the sample rate is too low according to the [Nyquist rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_rate).

Comment: Note that SciPy also has the `rfft` function for working with real (instead of complex) numbers.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Thanks, found it at [scipy.fftpack.rfft](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.rfft.html).

Comment: You can think of it as aliasing, sort of, but the sample rate is not too low… remember that there's only one period of your signal in the input, so the Nyquist frequency is 50 times higher than that. What is happening here is that your input does *actually* contain the sum of two different *complex* frequencies, one at f=+Fs/100, and one at f=-Fs/100. The imaginary components of the complex signals cancel out, leaving you with a real-valued sine wave. Aliasing tells us that a signal at f=-Fs/100 will be aliased at f=+Fs\*99/100, but it is not an issue with the sample rate being high or low.

Comment: When I say “complex frequency” what I’m being a little imprecise. The frequency itself is not complex, but the complex Fourier transform works with signals that are not sines and cosines, but instead a complex-valued combination of sines and cosines. Since complex numbers have a phase, we can consider positive frequencies to be signals where the phase increases over time, and negative frequencies to be signals where the phase decreases over time. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/4825/why-is-the-fft-mirrored

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Thanks again.  Your comments led me to [The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to Digital Signal Processing, Chapter 12: The Fast Fourier Transform](http://www.dspguide.com/ch12.htm), which has a good description of the different type of real vs. complex FFT, and also information about the implementation.

Answer (score 3):

The `np.fft.fft()` function returns the two-sided DFT spectra.
What you are seeing are the peaks for frequencies w and -w, where w is the frequency of the sine wave.

You can check this yourself by running [`np.fft.fftfreq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html) and plotting the results:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 2)
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*x)
Y = np.fft.fft(y)
freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(len(x), d=x[1]-x[0])

# Plot the results
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
ax1.plot(x, y)    
ax2.plot(freqs, np.abs(Y))
```

Comment: Thanks.  I added `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` before and `plt.show()` after to make it run.

Answer (score 2):

The Fourier transform

[image]

where `Xk` are complex numbers. While your `x` are real numbers, as a result, you get `X[N-m] = X[m]*` In your case, `N=100, m=1`, therefore, you have `X[ 1 ] = X[99]`

The link below explains everything,

[Why is the FFT “mirrored”?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/4825/why-is-the-fft-mirrored)

When dealing with real numbers, `numpy` provides another function `numpy.fft.rfft`

> When the DFT is computed for purely real input, the output is Hermitian-symmetric, i.e. the negative frequency terms are just the complex conjugates of the corresponding positive-frequency terms, and the negative-frequency terms are therefore redundant. This function does not compute the negative frequency terms, and the length of the transformed axis of the output is therefore n//2 + 1.

Comment: Thanks, good point with the complex conjugate value for `N - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

A standard full DFT or FFT is a NxN complex-to-complex linear basis transform that returns its result as an N element vector consisting of complex elements, each complex result element consisting of a real and imaginary component. A complex result is required to represent both the magnitude and phase of each frequency component (and thus not be information lossy).  The arctangent of the imaginary and real components represents the phase of each frequency component.

If you feed an FFT with a strictly real input (with no non-zero imaginary components), then you want the FFT result to represent a strictly real signal.  How is this possible when the FFT returns a complex result with non-zero imaginary components (required if the phase is non-zero)?  By returning two components for each signal, where those two components are equal in magnitude, but opposite in their imaginary components, so the imaginary parts cancels out.  You still need the imaginary component of each result element so you can measure the phase.  But looking at the entire FFT result, the imaginary components in the two complex values sum to zero, thus representing a strictly real input signal (with no imaginary stuff).

Thus a full FFT has to be complex-conjugate mirror **symmetric** when given strictly real input.

Thus you see (at least) two equal magnitude values in an FFT result for each frequency component in the input.  This is **not** true when feeding an FFT complex input with non-zero imaginary components, as common in many physics equations and signal processing algorithms.

Added: Why does an FFT have to return a complex result instead of just a magnitude and a phase angle?  FFT stands for **Fast** Fourier Transform.  One of the things that makes an FFT fast is that it is a linear transforms that can be computed with just multiplies and adds for the arithmetic (plus a bit of clever data shuffling along the way).  The real and imaginary components can be computed with just linear arithmetic.  Whereas computing the phase requires an arctangent (or atan2()), which is a much slower non-linear transcendental operator.